# Difference between a byte in a bytes32 and a byte in a bytes structure

Tags: solidity, data-types, type-casting

One can read in the docs:

> A `bytes` is similar to `byte[]`, but it is packed tightly in calldata and memory.

What does this exactly mean? For instance, according to [this link](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7702/how-to-convert-byte-array-to-bytes32-in-solidity), why should we convert a `bytes` object to a `bytes32` one using:

```
function bytesToBytes32(bytes b, uint offset) private pure returns (bytes32) {
  bytes32 out;

  for (uint i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
    out |= bytes32(b[offset + i] & 0xFF) >> (i * 8);
  }
  return out;
}
```

and not using:

```
function bytesToBytes32(bytes b, uint offset) private pure returns (bytes32) {
  bytes32 out;

  for (uint i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
    out[i] = b[offset + i];
  }
  return out;
}
```

Furthermore:

1. Why isn't it possible to set an element of a `bytes32` structure individually, but it is possible with `bytes`?
2. If I want to do some computations with bytes (litterally bytes, not the type `bytes`) by considering them as `uint8`, will it work for both structures by simply casting `b[i]` to `uint8(b[i])`? For instance, in order to get an `uint256` from these types, would the following code:

```
uint res;

for (uint i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
    res += uint8(b[i]) * (256 ** i);
}
```

work, be `b` be a `bytes` object or a `bytes32` one? Finally, are `uint res = uint(b[i]);` and `uint res = uint(uint8(b[i]));` two equivalent codes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic unit of work of the EVM, usually called a word, is 32 bytes.
This means that for the EVM, no matter whether we want to express 1 or 2^150, it will take 32 bytes, or 256 bits, to do so.

Everything costs gas in the EVM, including memory, so the fewer words the better.

> A bytes is similar to byte[], but it is packed tightly in calldata and memory
> What does this exactly mean?

Here, being packed tightly means that rather than using one word (32 bytes) per item, the compiler will "pack" multiple items to share a single word.

Let's look at an example.
Say we want to express the number 12345 as bytes, which gives [48, 57] in big endian (48 * 16^2 + 57 = 12345).
If we do not pack the bytes, this will give us:
[48, 0,...31 times, 57, 0,...31 times]
Now, if we pack the bytes, we can express this as:
[48, 57, 0,...30 times]

So as you can see, using a packed representation reduces the number of words we need to use. It is especially true with bytes, given that we waste 31 bytes per word without packing.

> Why isn't it possible to set an element of a bytes32 structure individually, but it is possible with bytes?

I think this is more a design choice of the Solidity developers than anything else.
I am not entirely sure about the rationale behind it but I can imagine that `bytes32` was mostly designed to hold short strings and making them immutable allows for some optimizations which could be tedious otherwise.

With this in mind, the code snippet using `out[i] = b[offset + i]` would work in theory but is simply not valid Solidity code.

The first snippet works but is, I think, a bit awkward.
b[offset + i] is a single byte, so masking it with `0xff` is a no-op.
The line could simply be written

```
out |= bytes32(b[offset + i]) >> (i * 8);
```

I am pretty sure that would be semantically equivalent but please correct me if I missed something.

Note that this conversion is not really related to the bytes being packed or not.

> If I want to do some computations with bytes (literally bytes, not the type bytes) by considering them as uint8, will it work for both structures by simply casting b[i] to uint8(b[i])

Yes, both uint8 and a byte represent 8 bits of data and have the same range, so this should work without any problem.

> Finally, are uint res = uint(b[i]); and uint res = uint(uint8(b[i])); two equivalent codes?

In theory both should be equivalent but the Solidity compiler, at least in the current version, does not allow to convert a byte into a `uint` directly so the explicit conversion to `uint8` is necessary.